# python staticmap api GeocoderError: Error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: python, api, anaconda, spyder

下記サイトの「urllibを使って特定の座標周辺の地図を画像として保存」を参考にプログラムを構築しました。html1とhtml2の部分を書き換え、google api key を入れたのですが、`GeocoderError: Error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`と表示されてしまいます。
まだ一度もstack map apiを利用していません。
改善策をお願いします。 
助けて下さい。

https://www.robotech-note.com/entry/2016/12/21/213024

エラーコード

```
File "<ipython-input-2-e038d4def69f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/name/map.py')

  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/name/map.py", line 19, in <module>
    results = Geocoder.geocode(address)

  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 129, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))

  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 212, in get_data
    raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)

GeocoderError: Error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%9F%8E&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=&components=
```

pythonコード

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
import urllib

def download_pic(url,filename):
    img = urllib.urlopen(url)
    localfile = open( "./" + str(filename) + ".png" , 'wb')
    localfile.write(img.read())
    img.close()
    localfile.close()

address = '大阪城'
results = Geocoder.geocode(address)
print(results[0].coordinates)

result = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(*results.coordinates, language="ja")
print (result)

html1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.687315,135.526201"
html2 = "&maptype=hybrid&size=640x480&sensor=false&zoom=18&markers=34.687315,135.526201"
html3 = "&key=APIKey&signature=signaturekey"

axis = str((results[0].coordinates)[0]) + "," + str((results[0].coordinates)[1])

html = html1 + axis + html2 + axis + html3

print (html)

download_pic(html,address)
```

試したこと
google stack map api の使い方をグーグルのサイトで確認しましたところ、署名キーも入れましたし、料金設定も行い、使用条件は満たしていると思います。何かアドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%9F%8E&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=&components=

このURLでアクセスした時に返るレスポンスのエラーメセージは、次のとおりです。

"Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"

つまり、APIキーが必要だということです。で、詳細は http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account を参照して下さい、とのことなので、このページをよく読んで下さい。

APIキーを取得する方法を書いた日本語のブログもありました。少し古いですが、このページも参考になりそうです。

https://nendeb.com/276

Comment: アドバイス本当にありがとうございます。質問に補足ですが、APIkeyと署名キーはすでに取得していてpythonのソースコードhtml3のところに入力しております。それでもエラーが表示されてしまいます。

Comment: @user31266 失礼しました... `print (html)`の結果はどのようになっていますか？

Comment: すみません。よくわからないですけど、APIkeyと署名キーをdeleteしても同じエラーが出てしまいます。何か問題解決のヒントになりますか？

Comment: `print (html)`で出力された結果をブラウザのURLに貼り付けてみて下さい。その際にF12キーを押して、開発者モードにして、どのような動きをしているか確認してみ下さい。

Comment: すみません。やり方が分かりません。print(html)でやってみた結果は何も変化ありませんでした。

Comment: よく見たら、それ以前に`Geocoder.geocode()`の問題ですね。GoogleのAPIの仕様が変わったのかも。時間ができたら調べてみますので、しばらくお待ち下さい。

Comment: APIキーを設定する行より前の`results = Geocoder.geocode(address)`の行でエラーになっていますね。なので、この行までに何らかの方法でAPIキーを指定する必要があると思うんですが、軽く調べた範囲ではその方法は見つかりませんでした。GoogleがAPIキーを必要とする範囲を最近広げたのに対して、pygeocoderが対応できていないのではないかと推測します。[このページ](https://bitbucket.org/xster/pygeocoder/commits/branch/default)を見ると、pygeocoderの開発は現在行われていなようです。なので、このライブラリーではなく、別のライブラリーを使う方がいいかもしれません。[geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy)とかを使えば、同じことが実現できそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。geopyをしようする場合最初のプログラムは、from geopy  import geocoders と記入し、他のpygeogoderの部分を変えたら、動きますか？

Comment: 試してみないと分かりませんね。ライブラリーが異なるので、文法の違いはあると思います。